# Heroku's DNS is causing conflicts with Google Suite MX records

Tags: heroku, dns, cname

Heroku DNS is causing troubles: cannot recieve any email at `myuser@stickersgallito.pe` that uses Google Suite as Mailbox.

My host provider is `Punto.pe` a peruvian company.

My projects is hosted in Heroku, in there I've 2 DNS:

1) `www.stickersgallito.pe` -> `ancient-crab-bwwmzXXXXXXXXXXXX.herokudns.com`
2) `stickersgallito.pe` -> `functional-wallaby-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.herokudns.com`

[image]

I need that people can visit the site entering: `www.stickersgallito.pe` or just `stickersgallito.pe`.

So I've entered these 2 records as CNAMEs in my Host Provider Registry Panel.

**Problem:**

I've also set up other tools like MailGun and Google Suite (to have mailboxes like omar@stickersgallito.pe).  MailGun functions correctly, I can visit the page either using: `www.stickersgallito.pe` or `stickersgallito.pe`.

But I cannot recieve emails at `omar@stickersgallito.pe`.

> I've consulted my Host Provider and the say that the record for
>   `stickersgallito.pe` ->
>   `functional-wallaby-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.herokudns.com` ***is the
>   problem***. It's interfering with other records.

They don't offer any solution, but point to Heroku for a response. 
Heroku point me to their documentation and if after following it's steps it doesn't work I should talk to my Host Provider.

My host provider says that if I can provide an IP Address from Heroku we could solve this. Heroku's doesn't offer an IP address as far as I know.

**Google Documentation to Set Up MX Records:**

https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en

What can I do?

DNSs in Host Provider:

[image]

Registers:

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

This is the kind of records my Host Provider allows me to enter: `A`, `CNAME`, `TXT`, `MX`.

[image]

When using `heroku domains` I get:

[image]

Comment: What you show is not what is in the DNS currently. A `MX` query for `stickersgallito.pe.` returns `stickersgallito.pe. 2h IN CNAME functional-wallaby-5kpzplwavcrzngxdlcfbt2rs.herokudns.com.` which is your problem. You need the `MX` record at apex pointing to your mail provider (Google?) for your email to work.

Comment: Yes, I did some changes but I've update the list of my records. I know that the CNAME `functional-wallaby-5kpzplwavcrzngxdlcfbt2rs.herokudns.com` is the problem. This is the one pointing to `stickersgallito.pe` (without www). What is APEX? Yes my email provider is Google.  I'm using their documentation here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CNAME record` is forbidden for the root domain exactly for this reason, it doesn't allow any other records you have to work the way you want them to. In the `heroku docs` they say to use a `CNAME like functionality` for the root domain, which is `ALIAS` or `ANAME record`, but don't use `CNAME`, your provider should not even allow you to create it.

You can configure `heroku` to work for a subdomain (e.g. www) and then use a `Web Forwarding/Redirecting` for the root domain to the `www subdomain`, if your DNS host doesn't support `ALIAS` or `ANAME record`. Contact them for more information.

Here is more info about the root domain configuration: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

And here is for a subdomain: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Comment: Please, see update 1. My host provider allows me these types of registers: `A`, `CNAME`, `TXT`, `MX`.

Comment: Well, in this case the only thing I can recommend you is to change your DNS hosting to one that supports `ANAME/ALIAS records`.

Comment: Which ones do you recommend?

Comment: I'm using `cloudns.net` for me and my clients' dns. They support ALIAS records (and the other records you have).

Comment: Route 53 does this quite nicely.